# Element width and text centering

Tags: html, css

I'm working with HTML and I need to insert a heading that is centered on the page with a color-filled, width-limited background, so that the color-fill of the heading element does not cover the whole of the page space.
Heres my code:

```
<head>

<h1 style="text-align:center;background-color: white;max-width: 500px;">Support</h1>

</head>
```

As this code goes, it centers the text within the limits of the element width and not the page. The entire page has a background image, which I want to remain as uncovered as possible.  I can center the text by excluding the width limit but this causes the element background to pass through the width of the page.  I want the color-filled heading element background in order to help the text pop from the page background.

Comment: don't put stuff in the `<head>` tags that is supposed to show on the screen. the head tag is for stylesheets, metadata, and other stuff that is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try putting a div around it, like

```
<div style="width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center">your H1 tag here</div>
```

Also, do as Pamblam said: don't put this in the `<head>` tag, but in the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp)

> The head element is a container for metadata (data about data) and
>   is placed between the html tag and the body tag.
>
> HTML metadata is data about the HTML document. Metadata is not
>   displayed.
>
> Metadata typically define the document title, character set, styles,
>   links, scripts, and other meta information.

Backing to your problem wrapping code in div tag would be a nice solution.

Speaking of centering elements you can find very nice tool here http://howtocenterincss.com/